# use custom fonts with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: css, fonts, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to use custom fonts in my PDF generated with wkhtmltopdf.
I read that you can't use google webfonts and that wkhtmltopdf uses truetype .ttf file. Can anyone confirm that?
So I downloaded a .ttf file from google webfont and put in on my server, then used the font face:

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: Jolly;
        src: url('../fonts/JollyLodger-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    }
```

and font family:

```
    <style type = "text/css">
        p { font-family: 'Jolly', cursive; }
    </style>
```

And now the text that is supposed to render with Jolly Lodger font doesn't appear at all, page is blank.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I tried with different .ttf files.

Comment: I tested this and was able to get a TTF working without an issue. Are you sure the src url is correct? Are you sure the TTF is working (did you try it on your system)? You might have better luck if you install the font on your server and just call it via regular CSS.

Comment: http://g33kinfo.com/info/archives/1806

Comment: It's working fine when using google web fonts with <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jolly+Lodger' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>. Maybe there was actually some problem with my .ttf file in the end...

Comment: Hi Marronsuisse, can you explain a little more what you used? Im having the same problem but it doesnt work anyway.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since it is a Google Web font you need not to write `@font-face` in you style sheet just use following link tag in your source code:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jolly+Lodger' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and

```
 <style type = "text/css">
    p { font-family: 'Jolly Lodger', cursive; }
</style>
```

will work.

By the way, in your code you are defining `@font-face` family as `font-family: Jolly;` and using it as `p { font-family: 'Jolly Lodger', cursive; }` that is wrong, because it's mismatching font-family name.

Comment: I don't use the link tag on purpose because I read that wkhtmltopdf doesn't work when retrieving the font directly from google webfonts. That is why I download the font and include it in my project. Using the tag works fine when I use the font in a html page though. You're right there is a mistake in my code I will edit it, but even though the name matches, the font still won't appear in the pdf file. I tried with a ttf file and a otf file.

Comment: I used the code in this answer and it worked fine (using wkhtmltoimage). Maybe the current version of the wkhtmltox tools have been updated to support this?

Comment: Doesn't work for me, for wkhtmltopdf on Linux 0.12.2.1 (nor on MacOS)

Answer (score 22):

I am betting you are calling wkhtmltopdf from a web wrapper using IIS. That's why some folks are saying that it does work for them. They are probably calling wkhtmltopdf from the command line, in which case it can resolve relative links in CSS URL()s but if you are calling it from snappy or the like you can get around the problem by specifying a URL like say `URL('http://localhost/myfolder/fonts/JollyLodger-Regular.ttf')` instead.

The inability to properly resolve relative links in CSS URL() tags appears to be broken in wkhtmltopdf 0.11.0_rc1 but some earlier versions might work okay. The same problem happens with other CSS URL() tags like when calling a background images - resolving the file location is broken. Interestingly though, in the case of images, if you use `<IMG SRC=>`, 0.11.0_rc1 is able to find the file, even if a relative path is provided. The problem appears to be limited to URL() tags inside CSS.

**EDIT:** I found out that if you use `file:///` with all **forward** slashes in the path then it works. In other words `URL('file:///D:/InetPub/wwwroot/myfolder/fonts/JollyLodger-Regular.ttf')` should work.

Comment: Thanks. `file://` URLs seem to be the thing with local fonts and font-face. E.g. `url(file:///my/dir/font.ttf)` on Linux. I mistakedly tried `local()`, but I think that's for something like referencing fonts without paths (out of the installed fonts directories).

Comment: Resolving relative links is still broken in 0.12.* using wrapper on *nix.

Comment: Using `src: url(file://myFont.ttf);` worked with one Font I am using (Note 2 forward slashes). For another Font there was no way to include it locally so I had to keep reference to googleFonts `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=myFont&display=swap');` otherwise the content was not rendered at all by wkhtmltopdf. Strangely it does not fall back on other fonts defined.

Comment: I have two questions on this topic.
First, how can I apply this solution on a ssl project.
Then can I add a format after the urls call?

Answer (score 18):

[As stated above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16972315/3384225) by [Yardboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9550/yardboy) we've found that base64 encoding the truetype font in our CSS works well. But I wanted to share some additional insight.

We use 4 custom fonts all uniquely named `'Light'` `'Medium'` etc..

I use openssl toolkit to base64 encode with good results. But you could alternatively use [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). Just be sure to strip out all other font types (`'woff'` `'otf'` .. ). We found that using `truetype` exclusively worked mysteriously.

*Encode file, trim output and add to clipboard*

```
openssl base64 -in bold.ttf | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy
```

In Windows you should install openssl and add it to path then

```
openssl base64 -in bold.ttf | tr -d '\n' | clip
```

or simply use [this kind of websites](https://www.giftofspeed.com/base64-encoder/)

*Add to css font src property*

```
   @font-face {
      font-family: 'Bold';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      src: url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,BASE64...) format("truetype");
    }
```

Rendered output will depend on your `wkhtmltopdf` version and flavor. Because our servers run Debian and I develop on OSX I tested on a VM locally.

Comment: Do you mean this will embed the font in the generated PDF documents?

Comment: Did you encode the whole url (with the base http: // ...) or just the path with font (/ fonts / ...) ?

Comment: this should help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35120327/3384225 it’s not a URL, the string IS the font file encoded in base64

Comment: Worked ! I recommend using  https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator under the "expert" option. to upload your fonts and convert them to Base64. as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16204485/473040.

Comment: Thanks @tgk this tip worked perfectly for me.  I'm stuck running IIS and using the base64 encoding of the true type font worked perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

If you have  .ttf file or .woff file then use following syntax

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Sample Name';
   src: url(/PathToFolderWhereContained/fontName.ttf) format('truetype');
   }
```

don't use `ttf` that will not work rather use full name `'truetype'` and if you have .woff then use `'woff'` in format. For my case it worked.

However the best practice is to use links to Google fonts API that is best if not getting that matching your criteria then use this above technique it will work

Answer (score 4):

I found that Arman H.'s solution (base64 encoding the fonts) over on this question worked like a charm: [Google Web Fonts and PDF generation from HTML with wkhtmltopdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721295/google-web-fonts-and-pdf-generation-from-html-with-wkhtmltopdf)

Answer (score 3):

I'll just add my answer here too, in case someone might need it.

I've been using [Rotativa](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa) which builds upon wkhtmltopdf, and what I ended up using was the following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "testfont";
    src: url("/UI/Fonts/609beecf-8d23-4a8c-bbf5-d22ee8db2fc9.woff") format("woff"),
         url("/UI/Fonts/1cd9ef2f-b358-4d39-8628-6481d9e1c8ce.svg#1cd9ef2f-b358-4d39-8628-6481d9e1c8ce") format("svg");
}
```

...and it seem's Rotativa is picking up the SVG-version. If I reorder them it still works, but if I remove the SVG-version, it stops working.

Might be worth a shot. Can't find any good documentation on why this is so, however

Answer (score 1):

After doing all the workarounds suggested (some which actually worked), I came across a way easier solution:

```
<style>
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat';
</style>
```

You can simply use the `@import` notation to include the font.

Comment: Does not work for me in wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3.2 (with patched qt) - win 8.1

Comment: @xtian It worked for me with django-wkhtmltopdf==2.0.3

Comment: Further investigation revealed that what didn't work in my test was importing and using a font with different weights: only one weight was used in all the document regardless of the css setting. This has been fixed in v0.13 alpha apparently.

Comment: @xtian that's good to know, so the weight of the font can't be specified? Would you mind linking to the bug?

Comment: I closed this bug report when I found out that the alpha version was working. I didn't get any official confirmation, but you can do the tests I detail in the report to see if it affects you: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3151

Answer (score 1):

I personally had to set the font family on a `div` (I initially wanted a `span`)

```
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CenturyGothic';
    src: url("fonts/century-gothic.ttf") format('truetype');
}

.title {
    font-family: 'CenturyGothic', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22pt;
}
</style>

...

<div class="title">This is Century Gothic</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Option for **unix** based systems

I was generating these pdfs server side. I was finding that fetching the font in the above ways was blowing up my pdfs e.g. `24kb` vs `1Mb`. I found this very helpful https://sanjay.cc/ubuntu-font-install.

Basically `wkhtmltopdf` looks in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype` for system fonts. So all you really have to do is add the font you want to this folder and make it accessible. Then you can just reference the font. e.g. if I want to use `calibri` then I can do the following.

1. Add the font

```bash
cp -r calibri /usr/share/fonts/truetype/
```

2. Cache font

```
fc-cache -f -v
```

3. Use the font

```css
html {
    font-family: Calibri;
}
```

***Note:*** add all font variations for best results

```
calibri
├── calibri-bold-italic.ttf
├── calibri-bold.ttf
├── calibri-italic.ttf
└── calibri-regular.ttf
```

Answer (score 0):

using @import not fetching the font, you need to add .ttf file to the project

Answer (score 0):

Just in case nothing has worked out for you yet:

Please try the standalone version of *wkhtmltopdf* instead of installable.

I had a similar issue but its resolved by using:

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox-0.12.6-1.mxe-cross-win64.7z

Unzip the file > go to bin folder > run your command.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is the relative URL in the font src that causes the issue, which is why it works with google api fonts - you specify an absolute url in the link src. In fact it seems to choke on any relative urls anywhere...

So this works:

```css
@font-face {
   src: url("https://yourhost/fonts/blah.ttf") format ("truetype");
   ...
}
```

but these do not work:

```css
@font-face {
   src: url("../fonts/blah.ttf") format ("truetype");
   ...
}
@font-face {
   src: url("fonts/blah.ttf") format ("truetype");
   ...
}
```

This was with wkhtmltopdf version 0.12.6.