# Wkhtmltopdf not displaying TrueType fonts

Tags: php, fonts, wkhtmltopdf

We're using wkhtmltopdf to render a PDF from an HTML page however fonts such as Verdana and Georgia aren't being displayed properly. We installed the TrueType fonts on our server using [these](http://corefonts.sourceforge.net/) instructions. Fonts are being set inline using style tags: style="font-family: verdana, geneva;"

Any suggestions on what we can try next to get these fonts to display would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try Arman H.'s solution posted over on this question: [Google Web Fonts and PDF generation from HTML with wkhtmltopdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721295/google-web-fonts-and-pdf-generation-from-html-with-wkhtmltopdf)

Base64 encoding the fonts into your css has worked like a charm for us.

Answer (score 0):

have you set up the fonts in your css correctly?

e.g.

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Verdana';
 src: url('verdana-webfont.eot');
 src: url('verdana-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
 url('verdana-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
 url('verdana-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
 url('verdana-webfont.svg#Verdana') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works for this problem but I solved my problems by installing true type fonts. After that wkhtmltopdf was able to display these fonts.

Ubuntu (18.04)

```
apt install fonts-droid-fallback ttf-dejavu fonts-freefont-ttf fonts-liberation ttf-ubuntu-font-family
```

Alpine Linux (3.9)

```
apk add ttf-dejavu ttf-droid ttf-freefont ttf-liberation ttf-ubuntu-font-family
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was the permissions on the installed fonts
which was installed in `/usr/local/share/fonts`
I had to set the permission for the fonts directory to `chmod 755`