# @font-face is not working on wkhtmltopdf

Tags: css, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3.2, font-face, wkhtmltopdf

```
**My code**
@font-face {
font-family: 'certificateitalic';
src: url('/webfontkit-20140113-085051/certificateitalic-webfont.eot');
src: url('/webfontkit-20140113-085051/certificateitalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/webfontkit-20140113-085051/certificateitalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/webfontkit-20140113-085051/certificateitalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/webfontkit-20140113-085051/certificateitalic-webfont.svg#certificateitalic') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

this is the code which is used in generatecertificate.html.erb

Comment: Make sure your location is correct `/webfontkit-20140113-085051/certificateitalic-webfont.eot`.

Comment: path is correct.i have put files under public folder.font style is working on html and font is not displaying on wkhtmltopdf

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467820/wkhtmltopdf-not-displaying-truetype-fonts

Comment: actually i downloaded fonts from online.i convert the folder using base 64 encoder and using in my app.but it is not working. is there any other software i have to install to make it as working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe its not just the fonts, check that when you create the pdf, you are receiving all the assets you need.

Las time i checked i had to use a helper provided by wkhtmltopdf called wkhtmltopdf_stylesheet_link_tag instead of the classic stylesheet_link_tag that you should have in your view/partial/layout.

EDIT: Actually, im using wicked_pdf gem (https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf), and there you have helpers like wicked_pdf_stylesset_link_tag, and solve most of the configuration of wkhtmltopdf config.

If you follow the configuration as explained there, and your font face is working correctly on the webpage, it shouldn't have any troubles in pdf generation.