# How can I set content font for pdf generation using wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I use wkhtmltopdf to generate pdfs.
It sets header and footer fonts explicitly but i could not find a way to set the font of content..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: [Try this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721295/google-web-fonts-and-pdf-generation-from-html-with-wkhtmltopdf/16204485#16204485)

Answer (score 0):

To convert **HTML to PDF** by **wkhtmltopdf** try to avoid woff font face. Use trutype format of the Google Web Fonts with base64 encode.

Recently I tried to use a google web font from Google Web Fonts. But in browser it shows correctly but it doesn't show after converting HTML to PDF.

Then after searching lots of from web at last I found tools to encode fonts to **base64** encoded format and also got CSS for **@font-face**.