# Generating pdf from Django html view hang intermittently using wkhtmltopdf with IIS on Windows Server 2008

Tags: django, iis, wkhtmltopdf

I'm returning pdf files with wkhtmltopdf from an html page in Django using the following code:

```
    currentSite = request.META['HTTP_HOST']

    params = { 'idOrganisation': idOrganisation, 'idMunicipalite' : idMunicipalite, 'nomMunicipalite' : nomMunicipalite, 'idUe': idUe, 'dateEvenement': dateEvenement}

    command_args = "wkhtmltopdf -s A4 http://%s/geocentralis/fiche-role/propriete/?%s -" % (currentSite, urlencode(params))

    process = Popen(command_args.split(' '), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

    rtn_comm = process.communicate() #better than wait this wait and return for us...
    pdf_contents = rtn_comm[0] #if want debug, index 1 return the stderror

    r = HttpResponse(pdf_contents, mimetype='application/pdf')
    r['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=fiche-de-propriete.pdf'

    return r
```

The code is working and the pdf is generated after 2-3 seconds but very often (intermittently), it hang around 30-60 sec before producing the pdf and firebug show me a "NetworkError: 408 Request Timeout. During this "hang" time, my Django site is not responding to any request.

I'm using Django with IIS on Windows server 2008.

I'm looking for any clue on how to solve that issue...

Answer (score 1):

The reason it hangs is because the server runs into racing/concurrency issues, and hits a deadlock (and you're probably using a relatively-liked asset or two in your HTML).

You request a PDF, so the server fires up `wkhtmltopdf`, which begins churning out your PDF file. When it reaches an asset (image, CSS or JS file, font, etc), `wkhtmltopdf` attempts loading it from that server... which happens to be the same server `wkhtmltopdf` is running on. If the server cannot handle multiple requests concurrently (or just doesn't handle concurrency well), then it enters a deadlock: `wkhtmltopdf` is awaiting on an asset on a server that is waiting for `wkhtmltopdf` to finish up processing, so that it can serve the asset to `wkhtmltopdf` which is awaiting on an asset...

To fix this in dev, just **[Base64-embed your assets into the HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721295/google-web-fonts-and-pdf-generation-from-html-with-wkhtmltopdf/16204485#16204485)** being converted to PDF, or temporarily serve these files from another machine (e.g a temporary AWS bucket). This should not be a problem in production environments, as your live server is (hopefully) capable of handling multiple GET requests and threads.