# Print HTML containing Font Awesome icons with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: html, wkhtmltopdf, font-awesome

I want to print an HTML page, that contains Font Awesome icons, with `wkhtmltopdf`. I saw this issue with Google fonts: [Google Web Fonts and PDF generation from HTML with wkhtmltopdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721295/google-web-fonts-and-pdf-generation-from-html-with-wkhtmltopdf), but this way is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the .woff file in your Font Awesome lib dir (no base64 in css) and it should work.

Comment: Can you explain this further with an example?

Answer (score 6):

I solved this by inlining the TTF version of the file like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url(data:application/x-font-truetype;base64,<< insert base64 encoded fontawesome-webfont.ttf here >>) format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
</style>
```

And then inlining the `font-awesome.css` file. BUT you need to remove the `@font-face` at-rule of that file, since wkhtmltopdf doesn't like multiple `@font-face`s that define the same font. You can do that by either inlining a modified version of the file or by using a RegEx to remove the at-rule (e.g.: `@font-face\s*\{[^\}]*\}`).

(I tried leaving the original `@font-face` intact, hoping a later definition would overwrite it, but that didn't work. The CSS standard doesn't seem to define what happens when two `@font-face` for the same font appear, if I read it correctly)

Comment: Worked for me too with headless chromium print to pdf. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any examples ??

I saw something similar in this issue:
https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/587

The filename contains a carriage return character, which is not a valid display symbol. The glyph you're seeing is one usually research for private Unicode character areas.

Comment: I have the same problem